# EasyAdmin (Symfony) does not update ManyToOne entities in Association Field with multiple relationships

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, easyadmin

We have a backoffice developed with **EasyAdmin (4.4.5)**, for a **Symfony (5.4.24)** project. Among other entities and features, we have a bunch of related entities, as shown in the following code example. The thing is, with these relationships, when we create an entity, everything is working correctly; but when we want to update one of the related entities, this change is not made (everything updates except for the relation).

We have been investigating and we see that EasyAdmin's CRUD forms sends the new data, and the new values goes through the "setXxxx" functions of the modified entities. But those entities, when they reach the "updateEntity()" function, arrive with the old related data.

Can someone tell us if this situation is due to a bad configuration of the entities, or if there is an error in the code, or if it's a Symfony or Doctrine cache problem, or if it is a bug in EasyAdmin?

We have not been able to solve this situation.

Thank you so much.

PD: The number "2" in the entities name is because I generated an example of code from our project, simplified to be able to explain the case.

Entities:

```
// namespace App\Module\AC2\Entity\Manufacturer2;
class Manufacturer2 implements EntityInterface
{
    use IdEntityTrait;
    use NameEntityTrait;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.systemRanges.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: Collection::class, message: 'trans.assert.systemRanges.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[Assert\All([
        new Assert\Type([Key::TYPE => SystemRange2::class, Key::MESSAGE => 'trans.assert.systemRanges.all.type'])
    ])]
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: SystemRange2::class, mappedBy: 'manufacturer', orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $systemRanges;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.acModels.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: Collection::class, message: 'trans.assert.acModels.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[Assert\All([
        new Assert\Type([Key::TYPE => ACModel2::class, Key::MESSAGE => 'trans.assert.acModels.all.type'])
    ])]
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: ACModel2::class, mappedBy: 'manufacturer', orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $acModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setId();
        $this->systemRanges = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->acModels     = new ArrayCollection();
    }
public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    public function getSystemRanges(): Collection
    {
        return $this->systemRanges;
    }

    public function addSystemRange(SystemRange2 $systemRange): self
    {
        if (!$this->systemRanges->contains($systemRange)) {
            $this->systemRanges->add($systemRange);
            $systemRange->setManufacturer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSystemRange(SystemRange2 $systemRange): self
    {
        if ($this->systemRanges->removeElement($systemRange)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($systemRange->getManufacturer() === $this) {
                $systemRange->setManufacturer(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getACModels(): Collection
    {
        return $this->acModels;
    }

    public function addACModel(ACModel2 $acModel): self
    {
        if (!$this->acModels->contains($acModel)) {
            $this->acModels->add($acModel);
            $acModel->setManufacturer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeACModel(ACModel2 $acModel): self
    {
        if ($this->acModels->removeElement($acModel)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($acModel->getManufacturer() === $this) {
                $acModel->setManufacturer(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
// namespace App\Module\AC2\Entity\SystemRange2;
class SystemRange2 implements EntityInterface
{
    use IdEntityTrait;
    use NameEntityTrait;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.manufacturer.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: Manufacturer2::class, message: 'trans.assert.manufacturer.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Manufacturer2::class, inversedBy: 'systemRanges')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Manufacturer2 $manufacturer = null;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.lines.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: Collection::class, message: 'trans.assert.lines.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[Assert\All([
        new Assert\Type([Key::TYPE => Line2::class, Key::MESSAGE => 'trans.assert.lines.all.type'])
    ])]
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Line2::class, mappedBy: 'systemRange', orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $lines;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.acModels.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: Collection::class, message: 'trans.assert.acModels.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[Assert\All([
        new Assert\Type([Key::TYPE => ACModel2::class, Key::MESSAGE => 'trans.assert.acModels.all.type'])
    ])]
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: ACModel2::class, mappedBy: 'systemRange', orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $acModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setId();
        $this->lines    = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->acModels = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    public function getManufacturer(): ?Manufacturer2
    {
        return $this->manufacturer;
    }

    public function setManufacturer(?Manufacturer2 $manufacturer): self
    {
        $this->manufacturer = $manufacturer;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLines(): Collection
    {
        return $this->lines;
    }

    public function addLine(Line2 $line): self
    {
        if (!$this->lines->contains($line)) {
            $this->lines->add($line);
            $line->setSystemRange($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLine(Line2 $line): self
    {
        if ($this->lines->removeElement($line)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($line->getSystemRange() === $this) {
                $line->setSystemRange(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getACModels(): Collection
    {
        return $this->acModels;
    }

    public function addACModel(ACModel2 $acModel): self
    {
        if (!$this->acModels->contains($acModel)) {
            $this->acModels->add($acModel);
            $acModel->setSystemRange($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeACModel(ACModel2 $acModel): self
    {
        if ($this->acModels->removeElement($acModel)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($acModel->getSystemRange() === $this) {
                $acModel->setSystemRange(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
// namespace App\Module\AC2\Entity\Line2;
class Line2 implements EntityInterface
{
    use IdEntityTrait;
    use NameEntityTrait;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.systemRange.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: SystemRange2::class, message: 'trans.assert.systemRange.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: SystemRange2::class, inversedBy: 'lines')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?SystemRange2 $systemRange = null;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.acModels.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: Collection::class, message: 'trans.assert.acModels.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[Assert\All([
        new Assert\Type([Key::TYPE => ACModel2::class, Key::MESSAGE => 'trans.assert.acModels.all.type'])
    ])]
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: ACModel2::class, mappedBy: 'line', orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $acModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setId();
        $this->acModels = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    public function getSystemRange(): ?SystemRange2
    {
        return $this->systemRange;
    }

    public function setSystemRange(?SystemRange2 $systemRange): self
    {
        $this->systemRange = $systemRange;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getACModels(): Collection
    {
        return $this->acModels;
    }

    public function addACModel(ACModel2 $acModel): self
    {
        if (!$this->acModels->contains($acModel)) {
            $this->acModels->add($acModel);
            $acModel->setLine($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeACModel(ACModel2 $acModel): self
    {
        if ($this->acModels->removeElement($acModel)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($acModel->getLine() === $this) {
                $acModel->setLine(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
// namespace App\Module\AC2\Entity\ACModel2;
class ACModel2 implements EntityInterface
{
    use IdEntityTrait;
    use NameEntityTrait;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.systemRange.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: SystemRange2::class, message: 'trans.assert.systemRange.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: SystemRange2::class, inversedBy: 'acModels')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?SystemRange2 $systemRange = null;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.line.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: Line2::class, message: 'trans.assert.line.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Line2::class, inversedBy: 'acModels')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Line2 $line = null;

    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'trans.assert.manufacturer.notNull')]
    #[Assert\Type(type: Manufacturer2::class, message: 'trans.assert.manufacturer.type')]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Manufacturer2::class, inversedBy: 'acModels')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Manufacturer2 $manufacturer = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setId();
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    public function getSystemRange(): ?SystemRange2
    {
        return $this->systemRange;
    }

    public function setSystemRange(?SystemRange2 $systemRange): self
    {
        $this->systemRange = $systemRange;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLine(): ?Line2
    {
        return $this->line;
    }

    public function setLine(?Line2 $line): self
    {
        $this->line = $line;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getManufacturer(): ?Manufacturer2
    {
        return $this->manufacturer;
    }

    public function setManufacturer(?Manufacturer2 $manufacturer): self
    {
        $this->manufacturer = $manufacturer;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Workflow in images:

[Define manufacturers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELeEV.png)

[Define SystemRange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfACs.png)

[Define Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBv16.png)

[Define ACModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA7mi.png)

[Try to update Manufacturer in ACModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYJOC.png)

We have tried: Check the circular references of the entities, configure the Symfony and Doctrine cache so that it does not run, keep track of the value changes in the entities, we have also tried to remove some of the relations of the entities (just for testing), ...

We expected that you could change any of the related entities, and save the change normally from EasyAdmin.

**UPDATED - 10/07/2023**

We have been reviewing the case, and we have found the reason that prevents updating the related entities.

It turns out that the "#[Assert\Valid]" validation of the entity we are updating causes the related entity to not be changed because even though the "setXxxx()" executes fine (the new related entity arrives ), later (assume at the time of execution of the Assert) it is replaced by the old related entity.

This causes that when the entity we are updating reaches the EasyAdmin CRUD, the related entity we want to change is no longer the new one but the old one.

Is there something we can do or configure, so that the "#[Assert\Valid]" continues to run and it allows the related entity to change?

Comment: Do you have add/remove methods for your collection ? Like SystemRange2::addLine($line) / SystemRange2::removeLine($line)

Comment: Yes, the entities all have set/get methods, but we didn't put them in the example code so as not to make the post too long.

Comment: But I'm talking about add function that would update the relation from the inverse side https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#setting-information-from-the-inverse-side

Comment: Yes, the relationships are defined on both sides. We've updated the example code for entities with sets/gets.